# Iterate through a number starting at the end and adding every other digit

Tags: java

I am working on a school assignment, so I am looking for guidance on what I am doing wrong. This is part of a larger program, but I am trying to work on loop before I implement the rest of the program. Basically, my loop is suppose to iterate through all the number and then add every other number, for example:

if the number entered is 48625, then return the sum of 5+6+4. I figured that I would have to combine my loop with an if statement to iterate through each nth number, so this is what I worked out so far:

```
class testLoop{

    public static void main (String args[]){

        int num = 12345;
        int sum = 0;

        for(int i = 0; num > 0; i++)
        {
            if(i%num == 0)
            {
                sum += num % 10;
            }

            num /= 10;

        System.out.println(sum);
    }
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, this is not working. It returns 6,5,5,5,5. It is not adding the nth values as planned.

I also tried the following:

```
int num = 12345;
int sum = 0;

while(num > 0) {
    sum += num % 10;
    num /= 10;
}
```

But that did not work either, it returned 15, which is basically the sum of all digits in variable num.  I know I am close to a solution, it's somewhere between my two codes, but I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: If it's every other number, perhaps check a flag that turns on and off for each iteration.

Comment: You want to get the sum of the 1st 3d an last number?

Comment: You chose the wrong answer as the best answer. You don't even need an if block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int num = 12345;
int sum = 0;
int pos = 0;
while(num > 0) {
    int digit = num % 10;    // make it really blatantly clear what the DIGIT is
    if (pos % 2 == 0)
      sum += digit;
    num /= 10;
    pos++;
}
```

You needed a checking mechanism to ensure you're skipping half the digits. [You're trying to add **digits of the number**, not numbers.  Editor.]

This would also fix your first solution:

```
if(i%2 /*not num*/ == 0)
```

Comment: @Jim His attempt was close enough for me. He had the right idea in his for-loop implementation. And I did more then just give him the answer, I explained why he needed the change.

Comment: This is not a good answer. If block is not even required. Check user2468852's answer.

Comment: @Jean-Bernard Thank you. I knew I was closed but could not really tell why it was failing. I knew my for loop was closer to the answer, but could not tell why it was failing.  I was using the remained of the number instead of telling it to go every other.

Comment: Very nice answer, I'm debugging it on the IDE to figure out what exactly is taking place.

Answer (score 5):

Simply divide by 100. That will skip the even numbers.

```
int num = 12345;
int sum = 0;

while(num > 0) {
    sum += num % 10;
    num /= 100;
}
```

Comment: This is a much better answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
int num = 12345;
int sum = 0;
String str = String.valueOf(num);
for (int i = str.toCharArray().length - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++) {
    if (j % 2 == 0) {
        int number = Character.digit(str.charAt(i), 10);
        sum += number;
    }
}
System.out.println(sum);
```